# In Snowflake, how to reference CTE in following table

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

We have the following working query in snowflake:

```
with
    latest_track_metrics as (
        select * from track_metrics
        where "week_id" = (select max("week_id") from track_metrics)
    )

select * from latest_track_metrics
```

in an effort to clean this code up a bit, we'd love to refactor the `select max("week_id") from track_metrics` into its own row with variable name, as such:

```
with
    max_weekid as (select max("week_id") from track_metrics),
    latest_track_metrics as (
        select * from track_metrics
        where "week_id" = max_weekid // error on this line, not recognizing max_weekid
    )

select * from latest_track_metrics
```

However the latter query returns the error `Error: invalid identifier 'MAX_WEEKID' (line 5)`. We've tried to wrap the `max_weekid` with parenthesis, quotes, backticks, etc. all with no luck. Is it possible to call a CTE in this manner?

Comment: treat max_weekid as a subquery or a table.. instead of WHERE week_id= you should be joining it together with track_metrics with a JOIN clause and then it will behave like you expect.

Comment: join the table and then, I assume, filter for the values matching the value from max_weekid? Will give this a try.

Comment: yes, and also alias the max(week_id) as well so you can refer to it.  Theres another answer posted which uses QUALIFY and I actually prefer that way too.... its a good function to learn and keep in your toolbox.

Comment: Unless the query you posted is just a portion of a larger query, you don't really need the CTE there and your query looks clean as is. Unlike corelated sub-queries, I find uncorrelated sub-queries in where clause quite palatable and dare I say, more readable.

Comment: the query will be growing in size. query for latest value, 2nd latest value, then join two tables together, than compute metrics & analyze results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using QUALIFY and windowed MAX:

```
with latest_track_metrics as (
   select * 
   from track_metrics
   qualify "week_id" = max("week_id") over()
)
select * 
from latest_track_metrics;
```

Comment: Is this a snowflake-unique solution here? I haven't seen qualify before but I am not too deep into SQL so perhaps this is available in other languages. Like this as a solution.

Comment: @Canovice It is a language extension present in Terradata, Snowflake and probably other RDBMSes.

Answer (score 1):

Treat `max_weekid` as a subquery or a table.

Instead of `WHERE week_id =` , you should be joining it together with track_metrics with a `JOIN` clause.

Perhaps something like this:

```
with
    max_weekid as (select max("week_id") AS M from track_metrics),
    latest_track_metrics as (
        select * from track_metrics
        inner join max_weekid
        on track_metrics.week_id = max_weekid.M)

select * from latest_track_metrics
```

Comment: While this is correct for how to use the CTE, you will be pulling though the values from `max_weekid` table, so if you aliased `from track_metrics as tm` then the select could be `select tm.*`

Answer (score 0):

The error is that you are matching a column "week_id" to a CTE "max_weekid". SQL should be

```
with
    max_weekid as (select max("week_id") as max_week_id from track_metrics),
    latest_track_metrics as (
        select * from track_metrics
        where "week_id" = max_weekid.max_week_id // CTE.column
    )

select * from latest_track_metrics
```