# In snowflake query, filter table for 2nd largest value in one of its columns

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

We have the following query per [In Snowflake, how to reference CTE in following table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72618669/in-snowflake-how-to-reference-cte-in-following-table) that filters using the max value in one of the table's columns:

```
with latest_track_metrics as (
   select * 
   from track_metrics
   qualify "week_id" = max("week_id") over()
)
select * from latest_track_metrics;
```

We are now attempting to query for the 2nd largest value in the `week_id` column. We've tried the following:

```
-- not all that close, (nth_value("week_id", 2) over(order by "week_id")) !== 2nd largest value.
select *
from track_metrics
qualify "week_id" = nth_value("week_id", 2) over(order by "week_id")
```

we've also tried:

```
with
    unique_values as (
        select distinct "week_id"
        from track_metrics
    )

select nth_value("week_id", 2) over(order by "week_id" desc) from unique_values
```

...which does return the 2nd largest value for `week_id`, however for some reason it returns an entire column (multiple rows) of that value, rather than just a single value. Something along this approach (getting unique values, and then grabbing the 2nd value in nth_value (descending)) makes sense. Perhaps there is an easier way to filter a table by the 2nd largest value in one of its columns?

Answer (score 2):

Qualify is your friend again

```
select * 
   from track_metrics
   qualify row_number() over (order by "week_id" desc) = 2;
```

With duplicate values, to select the 2nd set of duplicates you would use DENSE_RANK()

```
select * 
   from track_metrics
   qualify dense_rank() over (order by "week_id" desc) = 2;
```

Comment: This doesn't work as intended as the `week_id` column can have duplicate values. For example the `week_id` values may be `[8, 8, 8, 8, 7, 7, 7, 4, 3, 2, 5]` and we'd like to keep all rows where `week_id = 7`, where 7 is the 2nd largest unique value.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if this works for you:

```
create table track_metrics(week_id INT);
insert into track_metrics values(8), (8), (8), (8), (7), (7), (7), (4), 
(3), (2), (5);

 with unique_values as
       ( select * from track_metrics 
           group by week_id)
 select week_id, row_number() over (order by week_id desc) as 
 row_num 
 from unique_values qualify row_num=2;
```

Answer (score 0):

So as mentioned by others, [DENSE_RANK](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/dense_rank.html) seems to be what you want:

```
with data(week_id, other_vals) as (
    select * from values
    (8, 1),
    (8, 2),
    (8, 3),
    (8, 4),
    (7, 5),
    (7, 6),
    (7, 7),
    (4, 8),
    (3, 9),
    (2, 10),
    (5, 11)
)
select *
from data
qualify dense_rank() over (order by week_id desc) = 2;
```

gives:

| WEEK_ID | OTHER_VALS |
| --- | --- |
| 7 | 5 |
| 7 | 6 |
| 7 | 7 |